# No module named 'Pyqt5.QtChart'

Tags: python, pyqt5

In the book which i study, save my work as ui extension in the resource folder.
But I couldn't find the resource folder. Should I make a new one?

Is it because I can't put my work in the right place?
Or is it a matter of running pyqt5?

python 3.7, Pyqt5 5.13.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install PyQtChart (it should use the same version of Qt that PyQt5 uses).

In your case:

```
python -m pip install pyqtchart==5.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

PyQtChart-Qt5

python -m pip install pyqtchart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).